# Is the earning of them halal? Read the description

Tags: halal-haram, sharia, muslim-practices, halal-certification

In our local market there are some mills where you can grind your masala (ingredients for cooking i.e. Coriander, Red Pepper, Turmeric and Rice, Wheat etc. too).
They charge a certain amount of money (as par the market prices)  for per Kilogram, and there is no deal with the customers' that besides money they will cut 100gm of ingredients from per kg.

For your better understanding lemme give you an example, suppose you go to the mills market for grinding your 2kg and 500gm Turmeric and it will cost around  106.16 BDT (1 Dollar), and they will return to you after grinding your Turmeric less than 2kg and 100gms or 200gms. Around 300gms of Turmeric is vanished, when you ask them why you get less amount of that of you gave them to grind, they will reply that "Don't you know that by grinding they weight of every substance reduce? and for that we take 100gms from per 1kg ingredient!" and you will realise that there would no benefit of bargaining with them about the lose of your products and even there’s no accountable for that, no one's nowadays even caring about it anymore, it’s now the norms of that market, you go there to grind your products with a specific amount of weight and you come back with an weight which is definitely questionable, and you're gonna wonder about the decrease of your products even though you know that by grinding there would definitely some reduction but not that much that they are taking from your products, they even have set a certain reduction weight from per kilograms!!.

And if you're from the local people, you will certainly know that these mills sell those masala and grind products afterwards in the market at a high price and many heinous things you name it. A dishonest man and who doesn’t fear Allah can do anything to accomplishe their job!

Question :- the owner of those mills or the persons who run those mills pray regularly, give charity (sometimes misbehaves with the customers), dress like maulana, keep big beards and the like of sunnah acts, anyway, is their earning halal?